# How to calculate area percentage from polygons from one shapefile within another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, field-calculator, area

I'm working on a project where I have to create python code that takes land-use data and adds a percentage field for each land-use category in a Census Tract shapefile. I've been trying to work with the steps manually in ArcGIS before developing the code, but I've had problems getting there.

Basically, I have a land-use shapefile with over 100,000 parcels categorized by land-use category (i.e., Residential, Commercial, etc.) as well as a Census tract shapefile. Within the Census Tract shapefile, I need to add a field with the percentage of area of each land-use category to be applied to each individual Census tract.

I've been working on this for hours and haven't gotten far at all. Could anyone offer any insight as to some steps I should try? I've tried intersecting, dissolving, joining tables (does not work) and more to no avail.